# How to resolve an error 'list' object has no attribute 'iterdi'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

I am working on an image dataset. When I am writing for loop I find the following error. That is

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iterdi'`

in line

```
for class_folder_path in DATA_FOLDER.iterdir():
```

My code:

```
 max_print_subfolders = 4
max_print_files_per_folder = 3
subfolder_counter = 0
for class_folder_path in DATA_FOLDER.iterdir():
    subfolder_counter += 1
    if subfolder_counter > max_print_subfolders:
        print(str('/content/DATA_FOLDER') + "more subfolders in this folder...")
        break
    file_counter = 0
    for image_path in class_folder_path.glob("*.png"):
        file_counter += 1
        if file_counter > max_print_files_per_folder:
            print(str(class_folder_path / '...') + "more files in this folder...\n")
            break
        print(image_path)
```

Error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iterdi'`

Comment: Are you certain the error didn't say `object has no attribute 'iterdir'`?  Or that you used `iterdi` instead of `iterdir` in your actual code?

Comment: `DATA_FOLDER` isn't defined in your example.

Comment: `DATA_FOLDER` is evidently a `list`, not a `Path` object. Double check your data.

Comment: Yes it is iterdir @scothunter

Comment: `listdir` returns a list, and lists don't have that method. Do you mean just `for class_folder_path in DATA_FOLDER:`?

Comment: Yes, I applied this as `for class_folder_path in DATA_FOLDER:` but I am facing another error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'glob'` in line 
`for image_path in class_folder_path.glob("*.png"):` @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 0):

What is DATA_FOLDER? that should be a path (to a directory content) which you expect your directories are in it.

The `iterdir()` yields path objects of the directory contents.

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('D:/')
for _dir in path.iterdir():
    print(_dir)
```

Comment: Please do not use keywords of the python language as varaible name. This can cause some very ugly problems.